# In a relative layout how can I make the last element adjust to the increase of data in the preceding elements?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a layout as follows. The problem I have is that if the TextView of friend_name is very long it “pushes” down the rest and they overlap/cover last ViewStub of friend_last_msg
How can I make the last ViewStub to also “adjust” on this “lowering of the other widgets?

Or else how could I make that last view stub to be inside the LinearLayout and displayed to the left side and down?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
  >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/friend_img”
        android:layout_width="@dimen/friend_big”
        android:layout_height="@dimen/friend_big”
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
     />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/friend_img"
    >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/friend_name”
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/friend_img"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/layout_small_padding"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="top"
             />

        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/friend_sign”
            android:inflatedId="@+id/friend_sign"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout="@layout/friend_sign_layout”/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/friend_contact”
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            />



    </LinearLayout>


    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/friend_last_msg”
        android:inflatedId="@+id/friend_last_msg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout="@layout/friend_last_msg"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: did you tried fixing the height instead of using wrap_content..?

Comment: @Darkie:Fixing the height? What do you mean? Sorry I am newbie in android

Comment: ok fixing the height means you can write like
"android:layout_height = 35dp" instead of writing wrap_content, Now this height is fixed layout will not set it's height with respect to the content it is getting .... tell me if this problem still remains

Comment: the code you posted also had closing commas wrong also take a look at them I have corrected them in my answer and also if you want to fix the values you can do them like I told you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all enter the closing commas right like this then enter the `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` values according to your needs.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/parent_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:baselineAligned="false"
>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/friend_img[**"**]
    android:layout_width="@dimen/friend_big[**"**]
android:layout_height="@dimen/friend_big"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/friend_img"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/friend_name[**"**]
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/friend_img"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/layout_small_padding"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="top"
    />

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/friend_sign"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/friend_sign"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout="@layout/friend_sign_layout"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/friend_contact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    />



</LinearLayout>


<ViewStub
    android:id="@+id/friend_last_msg"
    android:inflatedId="@+id/friend_last_msg"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout="@layout/friend_last_msg"/>
```

Comment: I am sorry I don’t understand what changes you did. Could you please highlight what is different?

Comment: Can you highlight them?

Comment: @Jim I have highlighted them [**"**] like this in the code see them you didn't end the commas correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can to use this way:

Add an id -> `@+id/container` to parent

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/friend_img"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

For your stub layout just change to this:

```
<ViewStub
    android:id="@+id/friend_last_msg"
    android:inflatedId="@+id/friend_last_msg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/container"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/friend_img"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout="@layout/friend_last_msg"/>
```